# Mongoose private set field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Let's say I have this schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I want to avoid someone to accidentally do this:

```
const izzy = User.create({ name: 'Izzy', createdAt: "2000-01-28T01:04:30.809Z" });
```

I want to make sure `createdAt` is ignored, so if this is a new object being created (like my sample code) the `default` value would be used, but if it was an update, `createdAt` should be kept with its original value. So I'd like to somehow configure `createdAt` not to be explicitly settable.

Is this possible?

Comment: According to this [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4603), there is no built-in option to do it, but you can probably set an on-update pre hook to return the existing value of that field.

Comment: @TGrif I'll explore that solution, thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to use default value, you don't pass createdAt value.But since you are saying "accidentally" you can override the value passes using.

```
User.create({ name: 'Izzy', createdAt: "2000-01-28T01:04:30.809Z" } , (err,user)=>{
    if(err){
     //handle
    }
    user.createdAt = Date.now;
    user.save();
});
```

Comment: This is good, but only works when creating new objects. If it was an update, `createdAt` should keep its original value and never be overriden. My fault for not explaining in my question, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You may mark `createdAt` as `immutable` and set default value in `pre('save')` hook.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        immutabe: true
    }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    this.createAt = Date.now();
    next();
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```